# How to resolve "tablename.tablename doesn't exists"?

Tags: mysql, triggers

[image: Code]

I'm trying to create a trigger which should not allow the insert for those journey_dates which are less than the current date.

Comment: mysql> create trigger before_flysafeairways_insert before insert on FlySafeAirways
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    -> declare dummy date;
    -> if new.journey_date < date(now()) then
    -> select 'Invalid Date' into dummy from reservation where reservation.fid=new.fid;
    -> end if;
    -> end ; //
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'FlySafeAirways.FlySafeAirways' doesn't exist

Comment: ^ Please copy that code into the question, delete the comment, delete the image, and add in any further code or console log as text rather than a bitmap. This is an excellent skill to have for any Q&A site, so well worth getting used to - programmers don't like code as images, since they can't copy and paste what you are doing.

Comment: initially i tried to put the code but it was saying 'add more context' and i didnt understand what it was and finally uploaded the image @halfer

Comment: The reason for your downvotes may be because you've uploaded an image instead of code/text. Please replace it with text copied from your console, even though the question is resolved. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between table and schema/database for most RDB.

You seem to use FlySafeAirways as database name, not the table name.

Figure out what is your table name. If that is 'reservation', then you should use `FlySafeAirways.reservation` instead of just `FlySafeAirways`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a second database. Create table in that. Import every thing in this database from first database. Now delete the first database and rename the Second database to the name of first database.